# "Oracle "alter session set" via flask-sqlalchemy and cx-oracle"

Tags: python, oracle, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

how can I start a connection to an oracle database using flask-sqlalchemy and cx-oracle by sending these parameters:

```
alter session set nls_comp=linguistic;
alter session set nls_sort=Latin_AI;
```

In order to be able to make queries and sorts that do not distinguish, for example, between "Jose" and "José"

That's how I usually make the connection:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config

def create_app(config_name=(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

db.init_app(app)

from commons import commons_bp
from admin import admin_bp
from inventario import inventario_bp
from incidencias import incidencias_bp
from inconformidades import inconformidades_bp

with app.app_context():

    app.register_blueprint(commons_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(admin_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(inventario_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(incidencias_bp)
    app.register_blueprint(inconformidades_bp)

return app
```

and the configuration:

```
class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_ECHO') or False
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = None
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT = None
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
        'adminapps': 'oracle://ADMINAPPS:ADMINAPPS@SERVIDOR53/ENTECO',
        'incidencias': 'oracle://INCIDENCIAS:INCIDENCIAS@SERVIDOR53/ENTECO',
        'incidencias': 'oracle://INCIDENCIAS:INCIDENCIAS@SERVIDOR53/ENTECO',
        'inventario': 'oracle://INVENTARIO:INVENTARIO@SERVIDOR53/ENTECO',
        'inconformidades': 'oracle://INCONFORMIDADES:INCONFORMIDADES@SERVIDOR53/ENTECO',
        'documentacion': 'oracle://DOCUMENTACION:DOCUMENTACION@SERVIDOR53/ENTECO',
        'auditoria': 'oracle://AUDITORIA:AUDITORIA@SERVIDOR53/ENTECO',
        'navision': 'mssql+pyodbc://DB:DB.2020@SERVIDOR52',
    }
```

I've tried among other things:

```
'adminapps': ['oracle://ADMINAPPS:ADMINAPPS@SERVIDOR53/ENTECO', 'alter session set "nls_comp"="linguistic"', 'alter session set "nls_sort"="Latin_AI"'],
```

But I haven't been successful, I can't figure out how to do it, thank you for your answers!

Comment: Table 3.2 in the [NLS manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html#GUID-6475CA50-6476-4559-AD87-35D431276B20) shows these two parameters can be set as environment variables.  Note you may need to set NLS_LANG too.  I know some NLS environment variables are not deferenced unless NLS_LANG is set.  The native way to set environment in cx_Oracle would be with a [session pool callback](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#session-callbacks-for-setting-pooled-connection-state).

Comment: [ran out of comment characters!] If you end up executing the ALTER statements from the client, either explicitly or in a session callback, then wrap them in a PL/SQL block to reduce the number of round-trips required between cx_Oracle and the database.